# No Lightbox in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, internet-explorer-8, lightbox

Everything works fine, except for IE 8. Lightbox (jQuery plugin) is not working there. Instead of Lightbox, it opens the URL of the link. What am I doing wrong? The URL is http://keramiek.milacic.nl/tegels.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Its working dear.. Please check it..

Comment: It's not working here in IE 8 :(.

Comment: But I have check and its working well here with IE 8..

Comment: This may be a stupid question, and forgive me if it is, but do you have JS turned off in your version of IE8? If it's working for others but not for you then this is an option

Comment: No, but it's solved now: I showed it to my client and it's working there also. Hate IE 8 :P.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying colorBox as a much better solution than lightbox in every respect

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: using a different solution may not help his problem at all. If the issue has something to do with his browser or the way he's constructed his code then a different product will not help

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is the way you have initialised the lightbox. At the moment it targets `"#content a"` but looking at the source:

[image: Deep Navigation]

Maybe you need to target the objects specifically instead of using the umbrella `"#content a"`

Something like `"#content table td p a"`

Comment: No, that doesn't work; the problem is IE 8 opens the link, but it needs to display a pop-up.

Comment: It was worth a try at least eh?